# Problems with subprocess call with Python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

How can I run a subprocess with administrator privileges with a subprocess call?
 Example:

```
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe","Get-HotFix"])
```

I tried with `runAS` and `user:Administrator` and nothing....

I need this to execute the following command with cmd with administrator privileges with python. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

```
sc config vss start=auto
```

I think

`subprocess.call((["runAS","user:Administrator","C\Windows\system32\cmd.exe","sc config vss start=auto"]))`

but this doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for answer, Its true /user: sorry for that. But if i write /user:Mynameuser this should run no??

Comment: It should be `subprocess.call(['runas.exe', '/savecred', '/user:Administrator', 'sc.exe config vss start=auto'])`. The first time will ask for the password, but it will be remembered in the future. Again, note that using "Administrator" with runas.exe is a hack to get around UAC that should not be used in production code because this account is normally disabled. You can elevate a normal account in the administrators group using a task or service that's run on demand.

Comment: Of  course, installing a task or service requires administrator access. There are multiple examples online that show how to check for admin access and respawn via `ShellExecute` with the "runas" verb, which requests elevation via the UAC consent dialog.

Comment: Oh thank you very much for all this. I am going to try what you have told me. But I have no idea I'll start investigating about this last

Answer (score 0):

Make python code call Windows administrator privileges

```
from __future__ import print_function
import ctypes, sys

def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False
if is_admin():
    # The code to run is added here
else:
    if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
    else:#in python2.x
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, u"runas", unicode(sys.executable), unicode(__file__), None, 1)
```

If you run it under non-administrator privileges, you've run the code twice, and the first time you run it you don't have administrator privileges, and the second time you have administrator privileges.

You can refer to the following article:
https://blog.csdn.net/qq_17550379/article/details/79006655